# Click through canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am creating a doughnut (showing in pink) to represent data using the canvas. The problem is remaining area left by the canvas (filled with green in diagram) is not clickable in `IE` and `Safari` for Windows. I am using `pointer-events` for click through the canvas which is not supported by `IE` and `Safari`. Alternative solution is: I change the `z-index` which is very difficult implementing due to complex UI of the application.

[image]

Any hope except change the z-order? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try a [work around](http://jsbin.com/uhuto/1/edit) which works for older IEs as well

Comment: @ZachSaucier you should make this into an answer

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Did as you suggested!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around the problem in IE and Safari by using the offset and dimensions of each element associated with it. The following is an approach based on [this demo](http://jsbin.com/uhuto/1/edit). Hopefully the comments explain the code well enough

Pure Javascript

```
// Get all overlaying canvases
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"), 
// Get all elements that you want the click to fire on
    background = document.getElementsByClassName("background"); 

// Use click location and dimensions/positioning to fake a click through
function passThrough(e) { 
    // Check all background elements
    for(var i = 0; i < background.length; i++) { 
        // check if clicked point (taken from event) is inside element
        var mouseX = e.pageX;
        var mouseY = e.pageY;
        var obj = background[i];
        var width = obj.clientWidth;
        var height = obj.clientHeight;

        if (mouseX > obj.offsetLeft && mouseX < obj.offsetLeft + width 
            && mouseY > obj.offsetTop && mouseY < obj.offsetTop + height) {
            background[i].onclick(); // Force click event if within dimensions
        }
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
    // Force our function when clicked
    canvas[i].onmousedown = passThrough; 
}
for(var i = 0; i < background.length; i++) {
    // Toggle background when clicked (to show it works)
    background[i].onclick = function() { 
        if(this.style.background == "black") {
            this.style.background = "red";
        }
        else {
            this.style.background = "black";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

with jQuery

```
// Get all overlaying canvases
var canvas = $("canvas"), 
// Get all elements that you want the click to fire on
    background = $(".background");     
// Use click location and dimensions/positioning to fake a click through
function passThrough(e) { 
    // Check all background elements
    for(var i = 0; i < background.length; i++) { 
        // check if clicked point (taken from event) is inside element
        var mouseX = e.pageX;
        var mouseY = e.pageY;
        var offset = background.eq(i).offset();
        var width = background.eq(i).width();
        var height = background.eq(i).height();

        if (mouseX > offset.left && mouseX < offset.left + width 
            && mouseY > offset.top && mouseY < offset.top + height) {
            background.eq(i).click(); // Force click event if within dimensions
        }
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
    // Force our function when clicked
    canvas.eq(i).off('mousedown').on('mousedown', passThrough); 
}
for(var i = 0; i < background.length; i++) {
    // Toggle background when clicked (to show it works)
    background.eq(i).off('click').on('click', function() { 
        if($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        }
    });
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Hopefully it fixes your issue!

Comment: You are Genius Zach! I tried your code, its working fine, only a problem, still I can not click on button if created inside the 'background'.

Comment: You'd have to make the variable `background` be composed of each element you want to be clickable within the area, not as a container if that makes sense. So if it's the two buttons you want to be clickable, you'd make `background` be something like `var background = $('.buttonOne, .buttonTwo');` in jQuery form

Comment: Yes I am. Thanks for your help! And I wish you a very HaPpY New Year!